# node.js - detect exit of external process by PID

Tags: node.js, process, pid

Provided I have the PID for an already running process, how can I detect the exit of that process in Node.js?

For example:

```js
var pid = 1200; // any PID

getProcessByPID(pid).onExit = () => {
    // Code on exit goes here
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I know its an old post, just needed the information myself. You can do code on a process exiting by listening for the 'exit' keyword. 'code' is the exit code of the process.

```
const forked = fork(`${__dirname}/file.js`)

forked.on('message', (msg) => {
   console.log('message from child = ', msg)
})

forked.on('exit', (code) => {
   console.log('Exiting worker with code =', code)
})
```